# gawk process multiple files inside directory

Tags: awk, cygwin, gawk

I have multiple text files in a folder that I want to process through gawk, rather than process them each individually is it possible I can process them all at once without merging them into 1 .txt file

Example of script -

```
"C:\cygwin64\bin\gawk.exe" -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1 FS a[$2]}' email.phone.txt username.email.txt > username.phone.txt
```

Example of usage -

email.phone.txt - contains:

```
email@email.com:phoneexample
```

username.email.txt - contains:

```
user1:email@email.com
user131:email@email.com
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
user1:phoneexample
user131:phoneexample
```

but rather than process one of

```
email.phone.txt
```

files could i process a directory full of them?

Example -

```
C:/directory/folder/example
```

containing:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
...
```

Comment: What's wrong with `awk ... /directory/folder/example/file*.txt > out.txt`?

Comment: It seems you want to merge 2 file types, but it is not clear if the full operation is two sets or one set versus one type.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have **one** file mapping user to email, and **several** files mapping email to phone. Yes, awk can do this: just process the user:phone file *first*

```
gawk -F: -v OFS=: '
    NR == FNR  {user[$2] = $1; next} 
    $1 in user {print user[$1], $2}
' user.email.txt email.* > user.phone.txt
```